# How to make that variable $f defined how much "Freq" will be printed from column number 3?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, echo

I need a help with my bash script. I've problem with code:

`for v in $(seq 1 $f)); do echo $(grep "Freq" freq.log) | awk '{print$3}')`

because this comands printed `$f` times column number 3 instead should be printed `$f` values of `"Freq"` from column number 3.

It's look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrmrl.png)
Should be like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI3WC.png)

I don't know how make that variable `$f` defined how much `"Freq"` will be printed from column number 3. In this file I've plenty expressions of `"Freq"` but I need just `$f`.

For sure I pasted all content of script:

```
#!/bin/bash

e=$(grep "atomic number" freq.log | tail -1 | awk '{print$2}')
echo "Liczba atomow znajdujacyh sie w podanej czasteczce wynosi: $e"

f=$(bc  <<< "($e*3-6)/3")
echo "Liczba wartosci Freq, ktore wczyta skrypt to $f"

for v in $(seq 1 $f); do
echo "$(grep "Freq" freq.log | awk '{print$3}')"
done
```

Sample input data file; geometry optimization calculations in GAUSSIAN

```
      A                      A                      A
 Frequencies --    182.1477               202.8948               227.7144
 Red. masses --      6.6528                 8.2622                 6.3837
 Frc consts  --      0.1300                 0.2004                 0.1950
 IR Inten    --      0.8602                 0.4870                 1.2090
```

```
NAtoms=   35 NActive=   35 NUniq=   35 SFac= 1.00D+00 NAtFMM=   60 NAOKFM=F Big=F
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing but I think you mean `echo "$(grep $f freq.log | awk '{print$3}')"`

Comment: `echo "$(grep "Freq" freq.log | awk '{print$3}')"` ⇒ `awk '/Freq/{print$3}' freq.log`

Comment: Now it prints `$f` times all the `"Freq"`values from column 3. I want that print `$f` values of `"Freq"` from column number 3. @LéaGris

Comment: @CarolinePL do you happen to have lines with `atomic number` to see why you need that grep and tail ? Providing a dummy sample output of what you want could certainly help.

Comment: please post text of few sample input data lines, and post test of corresponding output data. We cannot copy paste from images.

Comment: You haven't absorbed all the advice given to you on your previous post on this subject.  But ++ for much better version as you've now included sample input. We still need to see sample output. Also, I'd recommend adding `set -x` before your `for` loop, and `set +x` after it. This will show you all the operations (steps) that are being executed. You have to change what you are searching for inside of each step in order to get different output, right? Good luck!

Comment: (Updated version:) If you now are using LéaGris 's `awk` only version, please update your code in the body of your Q. AND please remove the image links. You'll just confuse new readers of your Q. AND (finally?) there is no text string "atomic number" in your sample data. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your `bash` script converted to a single `awk` script:

#### `awk` script `script.awk`

```
/atomic number/{               # for each line matching regEx pattern "atomic number"
  e = $2;                      # store current 2nd field in variable e
}
/Freq/{                        # for each line matching regEx pattern "Freq"
  freqArr[fr++]=$3;            # add 3rd field to array freqArr, increment array counter fr
}
END {                          # on complete scanning input file
  print "Liczba atomow znajdujacyh sie w podanej czasteczce wynosi: " e;
  f = ( ((e * 3) - 6) / 3 );   # claculate vairable f
  print "Liczba wartosci Freq, ktore wczyta skrypt to " f;

  for (currFreq in freqArr) {   # scan all element freqArr  
    if (currFreq == f)          # if currFreq equals f
      freqCount++;              # increment freqCount coutner
  }
  print freqCount;
}
```

#### run command

```
awk -f script.awk freq.log
```

Comment: Thank you for your good intentions but still isn't work. Only printed `"Liczba atomow znajdujacyh sie w podanej czasteczce wynosi: " e; ` and ` "Liczba wartosci Freq, ktore wczyta skrypt to " f ;` that's all.

Comment: If it is not working for you. try inserting debug print messages. since you did not provide sample input data `freq.log` and output data. you need to debug it yourself.

Comment: something else is not right either, as the output looks to include the `e` and `f` variable identifiers. If they were empty/null due to some data parsing problem, that text wouldn't appear. Its as if this script has been processed inside of `bash` (or something else), note the included `"` and `;` chars in the output as well. @CarolinePL ? The output really contains `"", `;', `e` and `f`? Good luck to all. Update your Q with testable data and required output (as mentioned ~10 times now!)  !!!! Good luck to all!